# Initializing itimerspec struct - is memset a good choice?

Tags: c++, struct, memset

Years ago, I asked a question about [how to initialize a timespec struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462093/reinitialize-timeval-struct) to a *zeroed* state (nsec and sec equal to zero) with the minimum lines of code.

Many of the responses **told me not to use memset**, as this was not cross platform compatible and numerous other issues could occur. As a result, I adopted the following way:

```
struct timeval freshStruct = struct timeval){0};
```

Years later, I now want to initialize a itimerspec struct, which has within it two timespec structs. One way is for me to do the following:

```
struct itimerspec alarmTimeFormatted;
alarmTimeFormatted.it_interval = (struct timespec){0};
alarmTimeFormatted.it_value = (struct timespec){0};
```

I see other [answers here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973394/198004) which show using memset to initialize the struct itimerspec this in one line.

So now I'm curious -- is there something different about the itimerspec struct, or are these just bad answers? Is there any eloquent way to initialize the outer / inner structs with just one line?

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `itimerspec alarmTimeFormatted = { { 0 } };`

Comment: @Erik -- fantastic. Wasn't aware that would work, but it makes sense. I'm still curious as to the use of memset though and when it is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

It's still bad practice. Erik gave a possible solution in the comments, but usually in C++ we use constructors : `itimerspec::itimerspec() : it_interval { 0 }, it_value { 0 } { /***/ }`